# parse foursquare json feed using php

Tags: php, json, foursquare

Using Foursquare API it returns me the following JSON feed

{"meta":{"code":200},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":1}},{"type":"message","item":{"message":"OK! We've got you @ Place XXX. You've been here 2 times."}},{"type":"insights","item":{"insights":{"count":4,"items":[{"type":"pointsReward","image":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery-venue3.png","title":"First of your friends to check into Place XXX!","shareable":false,"points":{"image":{"prefix":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery-venue3_","sizes":[44,60,120],"name":".png"},"message":"First of your friends to check into Place XXX!","points":5}},{"type":"pointsReward","image":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery-venue3.png","title":"First time at Place XXX.","shareable":false,"points":{"image":{"prefix":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery-venue3_","sizes":[44,60,120],"name":".png"},"message":"First time at Place XXX.","points":5}},{"type":"pointsReward","image":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/category-outdoor.png","title":"First Plaza check-in of your friends!","shareable":false,"points":{"image":{"prefix":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/category-outdoor_","sizes":[44,60,120],"name":".png"},"message":"First Plaza check-in of your friends!","points":6}},{"type":"pointsReward","image":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery-venue3.png","title":"First of your friends to check in here.","shareable":false,"points":{"image":{"prefix":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery-venue3_","sizes":[44,60,120],"name":".png"},"message":"First of your friends to check in here.","points":2}}]}}},{"type":"leaderboard","item":{"total":18,"scores":[{"icon":"https://foursquare.com/img/points/discovery-venue3.png","message":"First of your friends to check into...
What I would like to do is to display the message "OK! We've got you @ Place XXX. You've been here 2 times." which is embedded in the second "type" tag

I'm used to do get this kind of value using a foreach function but with this one I cannot get it.
I need help from an expert, thanks for your participation.

Code Im trying to use without success:

```
$data = json_decode($response, true); // return array not object
      foreach($data['notifications']['type'][0] as $item) {
      echo $item['item']['message']; 
}
```

Comment: The data isn't valid json. Or perhaps you missed some parts?

Answer (score 0):

`notifications` is an array, so you can't hash into it with `'type'` like you are trying to do. You should iterate through `$data['notifications']` until you find an object with a `"type"` property of `"message"`. Then dig into that object's `"item"` and get its `"message"`. For more details about the `notifications` field in a response, see https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/notifications.

In the sample JSON you provided, to directly access the content you want, you could use `$data['notifications'][1]['item']['message']`. The `1` may change depending on what [API version](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning) you're passing in, but should be relatively stable as long as you keep using the same version.